# Can Poetry add package from AWS CodeArtifact

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-poetry, aws-codeartifact

I find multiple answers for how to publish package using Python Poetry to CodeArtifact and this is quite simple. But now I try to add the published package `poetry add sample-package` and it does not work. Poetry error:

```bash
Could not find a matching version of package sample-package
```

With `pip install` it works. But not with Poetry.

My pyproject.toml specifies to you my CodeArtifact repo as default. No problem with this:

```ini
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "artifact"
url = "https://test-domain-1234.d.codeartifact.region.amazonaws.com/pypi/test-repo"
default = true
```

Did anyone figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I found my mistake. In the package that I publish I need to specify repository without `/simple` at the end. But for project where I use the package from CodeArtifact the repository needs to end with `/simple`.

Example: Publish package config looks like:

```ini
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "artifact"
url = "https://test-domain-1234.d.codeartifact.region.amazonaws.com/pypi/test-repository/"
secondary=true
```

And the publish command is: `poetry publish --build -r artifact`

For project where I use my package `sample-lib` the config should be:

```ini
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "artifact-repo"
url = "https://test-domain-1234.d.codeartifact.region.amazonaws.com/pypi/test-repository/simple"
secondary=true
```

And then Poetry command is: `poetry add sample-lib --source artifact-repo`